# Problems with appearance in XML Android

Tags: android

I want a screen to look like this:

![What I want to see]https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5L4g.png

And I wrote the following code to get something similar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
 <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:fillViewport="true">
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSendMail"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="mail@gmail.com">
        </EditText>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSubjectMail"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Escriba un asunto"
            >
        </EditText>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/txtBodyMail"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Escribe el mensaje aquí."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine">
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSendMail"
            android:text="Send" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

But when I wrote the EditText that will contain the body of the mail, I put 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

I can't see the button. I'm sure that the EditText that "fills" parent is hiding it, but I don't know what property to set if I want the EditText to be as big as the rest of the Screen...

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your xml a bit. I think your body edittext should scroll and not the whole layout. So I removed the scrollview. Here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSendMail"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="mail@gmail.com">
        </EditText>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/txtSubjectMail"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Escriba un asunto"
            >
        </EditText>
        <EditText 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/txtBodyMail"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:text="Escribe el mensaje aquí."
            android:inputType="textMultiLine">
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btnSendMail"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Send" >
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

If you want it as earlier, you can use your own xml just notice the body edittext attributes should be

```
layout_height="0dip"
layout_weight="1.0"
```

This tells the parent that this view should take the remaining space after all the other child views.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution. But I wanted to scroll the whole screen, so I didn't remove if from my code, but the height and the weight solved my problem :)